# Lua: has the behaviour of garbage collector changed with Lua 5.3.2?

Tags: lua, garbage-collection

I'm facing a problem of memory leak in Lua. To understand how the gc works I have written a small script and the results are surprising (for me):

```
local mt = { __gc = function() end }

local function new()
    local o = { s = string.rep(os.date("%c"), 500) }
    setmetatable(o, mt)
end

local before = math.floor(collectgarbage("count"))
for i = 1, 100000 do new() end
local after = math.floor(collectgarbage("count"))
print(before, after)
```

I'm creating 100000 objects, each objet has a metatable having a __gc function.

As result I get :

- with Lua 5.2.4 : 25      130 (25 kb of memory at start, 130 kb at the
  end of the script)
- with Lua 5.3.5 : 25      17470

Lua 5.3.5 does not garbage the objects as Lua 5.2.4 did.

I used the same script on different Lua versions (5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.5) and this behaviour appears starting with Lua 5.3.2.

More surprising is that, if I remove the __gc function, the results are quite the same for all Lua versions.

Do you think that I'm missing something or is it a bug introduced in Lua 5.3.2 ?

Edit : this script behaves with Lua 5.4.0 as with Lua 5.3.1. So the bug is solved.

Comment: It is not a bug regardless. Garbage collection is not, and never has been, promised to *immediately* remove unreachable objects. The system only promises to do so "eventually".

Comment: It seems some GC parameters have been changed between 5.3.1 and 5.3.2

Comment: Even if I don't understant why the behavior is changing when __gc is defined, I will call collectgarbage() from time to time to reduce the memory usage.

Comment: On the Lua mailing-list, I found something close to my question (http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2017-07/msg00117.html).  Perhaps will I also open a thread on the mailing-list to receive confirmation that it's the same bug (or not !)

Comment: I made a test with Lua 5.4.0-beta and I get the same results as with Lua 5.2.4. I'll wait until Lua 5.4.0 is released to confirm that the bug is solved

Comment: I confirm that the behavior in Lua 5.4.0 is the same as the one in Lua 5.3.1 and earlier. The bug is solved.